# (lldb) error with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting an lldb error whenever I click on a specific tab. The tab is called Account and its supposed to pull data from a child node called "requests" and display that data in a list(table view controller).

I've done this multiple times before. I'm even using my own recycled code for this task, but the error keeps showing up. I've already made sure each button/label is connected to the view controller and I've made sure none are disconnected.

The error message is saying that my request object isn't key-code compliant, but that's not the case either. **What else could it be?**
This is the code along with some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot from Firebase that shows the requests node]

[image: requests object]

Here is the method I'm using. **The error only comes up when I call this function.** Other than that, the screen is just blank, so I figured that the issue has to be within the function. btw, requestsArray is an array of requests declared as such: `var requestsArray = [requests]()`
[image]

Heres the rest of the code from that view controller:
[image]

***EDIT***

[image]

Comment: `.chillAdded` will be called only when something is added, try to use `.value` instead to get a snapshot of the entire data from that collection

Comment: I've tried using .value and I'm getting the same error

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please copy and paste your code as text into your question. Images can't be searched or referenced and they are harder to read.

Comment: First, it is `(lldb)`, not `11db` (note those are the letter `l`, not the digit, `1`). Second, that's not the error, but rather it is the prompt from the `lldb` debugger. Third, when it says it's not key compliant for something, then that's what the problem is. Edit the question, showing us the complete error message. Specifically, the end of that error tells us precisely which key it's looking for. Edit your question, cutting and pasting the complete, exact text of the error message.

Comment: @Rob I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4, the vars need to be marked as @objc like this

```
class requests: NSObject {
    @objc var from: String?
    @objc var location: String?
    ...
}
```