# Wire a button to the pin callout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I am trying to get the location that I am searching to connect when driving but it is giving me this

> Error Message : Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Can someone please help. I am using Xcode9 & Swift4

```
//Getting direction of location
        func getDirections(){
            if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
                let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
                let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
                mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
            }
        }
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orange
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Car"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("getDirections")), for: .touchUpInside)
        pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        return pinView
    }
}
```

> - thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal
>     SIGABRT
>         frame #0: 0x00000001150b9d42 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
>         frame #1: 0x00000001150f1457 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
>         frame #2: 0x0000000114d790e7 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
>         frame #3: 0x0000000114b0b91f libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 245
>         frame #4: 0x0000000114b0babb libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 265
>         frame #5: 0x000000010f9571be libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 97
>         frame #6: 0x0000000114b27159 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
>         frame #7: 0x0000000114b26e0a libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
>         frame #8: 0x000000010f9570dc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
>         frame #9: 0x0000000113b00a39 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 537
>         frame #10: 0x00000001155f29c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
>         frame #11: 0x00000001107295e8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
>
>   - frame #12: 0x000000010f038067 Map`main at AppDelegate.swift:12
>       frame #13: 0x0000000114ca6d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>       frame #14: 0x0000000114ca6d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>       (lldb)

Comment: Can you give us the whole error? SIGABRT isn't that helpful

Comment: that is all it gives me and also libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)  then pops up a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Look at the console, and/or debug session

Comment: It does not say anything. just have that message when I click on the car logo then it breaks and gives me that message

Comment: It should give more information if you scroll up

Comment: Which line exactly is causes the error?

Comment: I think you should use `#selector(getDirections)` instead of `Selector(("getDirections"))`

Comment: I tried #selector(getDirections) and it did not work.

Comment: It gives me this error once I click on the car logo. class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {       Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Please post the error like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149903/lldb-error-with-firebase here we clearly see the error of key-value coding compliant error,

Comment: You have provided no proof that the exception occurs within the code fragment you provided.  Couldn't the exception be occurring within your getDirections method?  That is why we all want to see the back trace in the debugger or console output.  You might benefit from reviewing [Examining the Back Trace](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/quickstart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH7-SW5) from the Debugging With Xcode Guide.

Comment: Here is what I have. It gives me this error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0) I am not sure what this means

Comment: After it crashes, In the console, where is says "(lldb)", try typing "bt". That should produce a back trace which you can paste into your question.

Comment: I did and it just comes up with lldb

Comment: Ok, now put your cursor next to the (lldb) prompt and type "bt"

Comment: * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001150b9d42 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001150f1457 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x0000000114d790e7 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x0000000114b0b91f libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 245
    frame #4: 0x0000000114b0babb libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 265
    frame #5: 0x000000010f9571be libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 97

Comment: frame #6: 0x0000000114b27159 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x0000000114b26e0a libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x000000010f9570dc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40

Comment: frame #9: 0x0000000113b00a39 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 537
    frame #10: 0x00000001155f29c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #11: 0x00000001107295e8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
  * frame #12: 0x000000010f038067 map`main at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #13: 0x0000000114ca6d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #14: 0x0000000114ca6d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)  This is what I got!

Comment: Very good.  Now, edit your question and paste that backtrace in there so that we can read it.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: Ok Ram, I suspect that your selector is bad.  What @3stud1ant3 said is totally correct about the syntax for your selector.  Xcode attempts to check the validity of selectors but it seems you can bypass the checking if you put some extra parentheses (as you have done).  Then, Xcode neither suggests corrections nor reports an error if the method/selector is misspelled.  So, please show the declaration of your getDirections method in the ViewController class.  And then let's try to fix your selector expression to match.

Comment: I have added the getDirections from the ViewCotroller. Thanks again

Comment: So, let's try this syntax in the addTarget call:  action: #selector(ViewController.getDirections)

Comment: @ozzieozumo I tried that and gave me Type 'ViewController' has no member 'getDirections'

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two changes that you need to make

First use

```
#selector(getDirections)
```

instead of

```
Selector(("getDirections"))
```

Second for **Swift 4** use

```
@objc func getDirections()
```

instead of

```
func getDirections()
```